# Does enumerateChildNodes sort through grandchildren?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Instead of using physics bodies to detect collisions I am simply using enumerateChildNodes to check if SKSpriteNodes intersect. Its works great for me when the SKSpriteNodes are both children of the scene but it doesn't work when one of the SKSpriteNodes is a grandchild. I have tried using // and / before the name of the SKSpriteNode to search through all of the tree but it doesn't help. Here is my code:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let red = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10,10))
    red.name = "red"
    self.addChild(red)

    let blue = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10,10))
    blue.name = "blue"
    self.addChild(blue)

    let green = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10,10))
    green.name = "green"
    blue.addChild(green)

}
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    enumerateChildNodes(withName:"red") {node, _ in 
        let red = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if red.frame.intersects((self.childNode(withName:"//blue/green")?.frame)!) 
            { 
             red.removeFromParent() 
            }

}
```

Comment: Are you searching for Blue and green or just green?  "//blue/green" is only going to get you green nodes

Comment: also, your green frame is relative to your blue parent, not to the scene.  Intersects is going to fail you

Comment: I am searching for only green nodes

Comment: mutliple or only 1?

Comment: multiple green nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here,  you are going to want to double enumerate, and you need to convert your frame.

The following code should handle this, but I have not tested for accuracy:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var nodesToDelete = [SKNode]()
    enumerateChildNodes(withName:"red") {node, _ in 
        let red = node as! SKSpriteNode
        enumerateChildNodes(withName:"//blue/green") {node, killMe in 
            let green = node as! SKSpriteNode
            let point = green.parent!.convert(green.position, to:red.parent!)
            let convertedFrame = CGRect(origin:point:size:green.size)
            if red.frame.intersects(convertedFrame){ 
                nodesToDelete.append(red) 
                killMe.initialize(to: true) //stops enumeration of green
            }
        }
    }
    nodesToDelete.forEach{$0.removeFromParent()}
}
```

Comment: ok this works perfect for me. however after a few tests it occasionally terminates due to an uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: probably because you removed red but something else needed it

Comment: it says that the collection NSArray was mutated while being enumerated, would it make a difference that the nodes are moving?

Comment: Oh yeah,  you can’t remove the way you are doing it.  Save it into an array and delete when done

Comment: do you mean that within the enumerateChildNodes I save the node to an array?

Comment: Yes, whatever red node you want to remove, save in array instead

Comment: and then where do I delete the node from?

Comment: I updated my code to show you how to do it.  FYI, if you want to be a successful programmer, you are going to need to apply yourself more when it comes to solving problems. Do not be afraid to go in and try to do things once somebody gives you a nudge.

Comment: You are absolutely right. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

why not just reference the children of blue when doing your checks rather than cycling through all of the hierarchy

```
if red.frame.intersects((blue.childNode(withName: "green")?.frame)!) { 
    red.removeFromParent() 
}
```

Comment: I'll update my question because I actually have enumerateChildNodes inside an update function